# transforming an empty object into a date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, object, clone

I need to transform an empty object into a Date Object like this:

```
let dest = {};
let src = new Date();

someFunctionToPushSrcIntoDest(dest, src);

dest instanceof Date // should return true
dest.setTime(0) // and all other methods fo Date should work as expected
```

I tried several solutions. My first attempt was using lodash' extend but

```
let dest = {};
let src = new Date();

_.extend(dest, src);

// but...
typeof dest === 'object' // true
dest instanceof Date // false
```

then I tried with

```
let dest = {};
let src = new Date();

Object.setPrototype(dest, Object.getPrototype(src));

// but...
typeof dest === 'object'; // true
dest instanceof Date; // true - Good !!!

dest.getTime(); // Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object...
dest.setTime(); // Uncaught TypeError: Method Date.prototype.setTime called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

then I tried `Object.assign` and various other permutations but I couldn't find a way to clone a Date into an existing object instance. Am I trying something impossible ? Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is this javascript or typescript? public or private properties in classes are not supported in javascript.

Comment: "_the need of recreating Date object references_" You don't.Theoretically seen, (de)-serializing entity A leads to another entity B where `A === B` should evaluate as false. The **content** of it must be of course similar. So, just pass the required values and re-create a Date object by using `new date(...)`

Comment: @stavros.zavrakas you're right the library I'm writing is in typescript, and so are exemples I put in the question but, at the end, what you get is javascript !

Comment: @KarelG Yes of course you're right serializing and deserializing A (the "container" object in the example) will create another object B (the "afterDeserialization" object in the example) obviously A !== B. In the example the two properties of "container" are referencing the same "ContainerObject" instance. If I did a `let afterDeserialization = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(container))` I would get an object where the two properties would hold two different objects containing the same data, and no prototypal inheritance information. I'll Edit the example to focus on Dates.

Comment: I removed all the stuff about WHY I am trying to do this, to focus the question on my need ! So @stavros.zavrakas and KarelG comments (and my answers to those comments) are no more relevant. Sorry

Comment: Impossible. You can only create a Date by using the Date constructor, as Date objects have a special internal [`[[DateValue]]`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-date-instances) that is the [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) of the date. You can't mimic it. You might create an object with properties for year, month, day, etc. then use a special function to get those values and use the Date constructor to create a Date from them.